# Google script function breaking when using else if statement.

Tags: javascript

For some reason my function falls apart after adding an "else if".  It worked fine when I had just if and else.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong.  It seems like it should be working. I'm not the best at this so please be nice :)

This is the opening function.

```
function SendGoogleForm(e) { 

var formData = e.values;  
var requestor = formData[1];
var newHire = formData[2];
var globalID = formData[3];
var startDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(formData[4]), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMM d, yyyy");
var newhireRole = formData[5];
var newhireStatus = formData[6];

if (newhireRole == "Food Care") { 

var mailBody = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('foodCare');

mailBody.requestor = requestor;
mailBody.newHire = newHire;
mailBody.globalId = globalID;
mailBody.startDate = startDate;
mailBody.newHireRole = newhireRole;
mailBody.newHireStatus = newhireStatus;

var mailMessage = mailBody.evaluate().getContent();

var subject = "NACCC Food Care Pre-Approved On-boarding Request for " + newHire;

var recipient = 'juan.miranda@testr.com';

MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, '',{htmlBody:mailMessage});

}else if (newhireRole == "Product Care"){

var mailBody = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('productCare');

mailBody.requestor = requestor;
mailBody.newHire = newHire;
mailBody.globalId = globalID;
mailBody.startDate = startDate;
mailBody.newHireRole = newhireRole;
mailBody.newHireStatus = newhireStatus;

var mailMessage = mailBody.evaluate().getContent();

var subject = "NACCC Product Care Pre-Approved On-boarding Request for " + newHire;

var recipient = 'juan.miranda@testr.com'; 

MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, '',{htmlBody:mailMessage});

} else {

var mailBody = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('specialtyMaterials');

mailBody.requestor = requestor;
mailBody.newHire = newHire;
mailBody.globalId = globalID;
mailBody.startDate = startDate;
mailBody.newHireRole = newhireRole;
mailBody.newHireStatus = newhireStatus;

var mailMessage = mailBody.evaluate().getContent();

var subject = "NACCC Specialty Materials Pre-Approved On-boarding Request for " + newHire;

var recipient = 'juan.miranda@testr.com';

MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, '',{htmlBody:mailMessage});

}

}
```

The Final curly bracket is in red and I have no idea why.  I tried commenting out different parts of the "if" statement but for some reason it wont let me do three conditions.  Any ideas? :/

Comment: It doesn't look like any error in this part of the code, there is more than this code on that file? Depending on your editor, the last red curl bracket may be just marking it to help you search the opening bracket

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be related to variable declaration, you're using `var` and re-declaring and such.

Looks like it is time to refactor, you're doing a lot of the same thing - so let's parameterize this so that it's easier to read and debug (and follow [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)).

You have a very common sequence of steps that construct an email, let's make this a function:

```
function constructEmail(file, requestor, newHire, globalId, startDate, newHireRole, newHireStatus) {
    let mailBody = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(file);

    body.requestor = requestor;
    body.newHire = newHire;
    body.globalId = globalId;
    body.startDate = startDate;
    body.newHireRole = newHireRole;
    body.newHireStatus = newHireStatus;

    return body.evaluate().getContent();
}
```

Then we can call into it and get the content as a return.

```
function SendGoogleForm(e) {

  let formData = e.values;
  let requestor = formData[1];
  let newHire = formData[2];
  let globalId = formData[3];
  let startDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(formData[4]), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMM d, yyyy");
  let newHireRole = formData[5];
  let newHireStatus = formData[6];

  let mailMessage = null;
  let subject = "NACCC Food Care Pre-Approved On-boarding Request for " + newHire
  let recipient = 'juan.miranda@testr.com';

  switch (newHireRole) {
    case "Food Care":    
    mailMessage = 
        constructEmail('foodCare',
                       mailBody,
                       requestor,
                       newHire,
                       globalId,
                       startDate,
                       newHireRole,
                       newHireStatus);    
    break;

    case "Product Care":    
    mailMessage = 
        constructEmail('specialtyMaterials',
                       mailBody,
                       requestor,
                       newHire,
                       globalId,
                       startDate,
                       newHireRole,
                       newHireStatus);    
    break;

    default:    
    mailMessage = 
        constructEmail('productCare',
                       mailBody,
                       requestor,
                       newHire,
                       globalId,
                       startDate,
                       newHireRole,
                       newHireStatus);
    break;
  }

  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, '', {
      htmlBody: mailMessage
  });

}
```

First of all, let's get used to using the [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) keyword to limit the scope of our variables. Next we'll create a helper method to do the repetitive work, then we will use the [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) operation instead of the `if / else if / else` syntax. This should make it easier to read, follow and debug.